# Measure concentrated at a point

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

What does "a finite random measure $\nu$ is concentrated at a point" mean?

And in this case, what is equal to $\int_{\Omega} x d\nu$ ?

---

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you define what a "random" measure is?

Comment: @David i edited my message

Comment: Do you understand the definition of a finite Radon measure over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and are just confused about the phrase "concentrated at a point"?

Comment: i don't realy understand the definition of Radon measure, an d in this case it is over $\Omega$  and i'm very confused about the definition of concentrated at a point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) or [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Radon_measure) for the definition of a Radon measure.

A measure $\nu: \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ is concentrated on a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ if $\nu(A^c) = 0$. Thus if $\nu$ is concentrated at a point (say $\omega$), then for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$ we have

$$
\nu(A) = \begin{cases}
\nu(\Omega) &\text{ if $\omega \in A$} \\
0 &\text{ if $\omega \notin A$}
\end{cases}
$$

For any measurable function $x: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, we have 
$$\int x d\nu = \int x(w) \mathbb{1}\{w = \omega\}d\nu + \int x(w) \mathbb{1}\{w \neq \omega\} d\nu = x(\omega)\nu(\Omega)$$
where the first equality follows because $x(w) = x(w) \mathbb{1}\{w = \omega\} + x(w) \mathbb{1}\{w \neq \omega\}$ and the second equality follows because $x(w) \mathbb{1}\{w \neq \omega\} = 0$ almost surely $\nu$.

Comment: what is the reference where you find that  $\int x d\nu = x(\omega)\nu(\Omega)$ ? please

Comment: and where you have found the definition of concentrated at a point ?

Comment: you complicated the answer by the edit

Comment: i do not know it

Comment: I thought you wanted further explanation of the integral. As for a reference, the definition of "concentrated" can be found in any standard measure theory text (e.g. Ash and Doleans-Dade, pg. 6).

Comment: Is this the book: http://www.lce.esalq.usp.br/arquivos/aulas/2011/LCE5866/ebooksclub.org__Probability__amp__Measure_Theory__Second_Edition.pdf

Comment: Yep that's the one.

Comment: i don't find the definition of cocentrated

Comment: @Vrouvrou On page 6, right before the start of section 1.2.4.